# Does anyone have an OpenGL ES 2.0 Qt 5 example working under iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, qt, opengl-es, qt5

Background: I built Qt for iOS in the usual way (by following the instructions [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/03/05/qt-for-ios-preview/)). I ran `qmake` in the ["cube"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/cube.html) example project directory, opened the output .xcodeproj file, and then ran it on my iPad 3. Instead of the expected cube I just get a black screen. I can tell from inserting `qDebug()` statements that the touch events are working, but there is no display, even though the Qt OpenGL API calls seem to all succeed. In the console there is only this:
`QIOSBackingStore needs to have the same size as its window`

I thought there was a chance this example would work since it's explicitly OpenGL ES 2.0-compatible but I guess there is some problem with the implementation. OpenGL ES 2.0 is too unwieldy and I'm not familiar enough with it to quickly diagnose the problem, unfortunately.

I've learned that Qt's OpenGL support is very good, so I would like to use it for iOS development if possible, rather than reinventing the wheel. Does anyone know what could be wrong with the example project? Failing that, does anyone have a Qt OpenGL project that works correctly on their iPhone or iPad?

Comment: I see. Then see my reply below. I think that is the only thing you can do. I have discussed this with the Qt iOS developer behind the project, and he also suggested to create a bugreport, and will take care of it. Thanks, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I submitted a bug. https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33418 We will see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: njahnke: OK, great, thanks. I have just sent the link directly to the developer as well just in case. Hope it gets fixed ASAP.

Comment: Flagging this interesting and useful question for closure as "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User." looks like was an improper idea in my opinion. The voting habit in this thread seems to be the unfortunate multi-user serial down-voting without any comments on what is wrong, etc.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the reasoning behind marking my question as off-topic. I'm a professional programmer trying to use OpenGL ES 2.0 with the Qt libraries for my projects. It's not like this is about installing service packs or something.

Comment: I fully agree. I think you asked a bleeding edge Qt 5 development related question. I think the people who closed it are incorrect. I have not even seen those nick names in the "qt" tag before to be honest. Not sure how much relevance they have to the topic. I will vote for reopening it. Let us see how qt skilled people will handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have an OpenGL ES 2.0 Qt 5 example working under iOS?

I have just had a quick chat with the developers and they claimed the cube example to work in the past at some point for their quick test. It may be that you are hitting a bug. I would suggest you to report this on the [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org) against the QtPorts iOS component. Tor Arne will eventually look at it when he gets there.

Having that said, he "hellogl_es2" and "hellogl" examples have also worked for the developers, and they should also work. Again, if there is any bug, please report it as iOS is a fairly new platform for Qt to be supported, so smaller bugs may occur.

As for for giving some background about the history of the iOS port: the main focus has been Qt Quick 1 for the last minor series, Qt 5.1. There has not been a thorough development and testing for opengl (including raw C++ code).

Lately, the development branch in git got v4 support (new interpreter engine) for the declarative repository which is a way towards QtQuick2 and proper opengl support implicitly. Until that, it is hard to say if there is something reliably working.

The people behind the post have not had opengl that much on the radar for understandable reasons. This includes for instance QGLWidget from the Qt 4 era.

The only official examples provided at the Qt iOS team are available at:

1) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/subattack/id659283830

2) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qtquicksand/id666273528

That being said, 5.2 and post releases will be improved, so it is worth watching.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the actual OpenGL ES 2.0 example working for iOS is called "hellogl_es2". The "cube" example I was trying has not yet been fixed to run on iOS. It is also OpenGL ES 2.0, but there is probably some problem with the implementation that I am not qualified to remedy at this time.

Anyway, if you want to see OpenGL ES 2.0 with QGLWidget running under iOS today, deploy the "hellogl" example. It is working fine on my iPad 3 at ~60 fps.